# Change characters to lowercase

Tags: powershell, tr

I am trying to make all values in the 11th column of my .csv file lowercase. I know I can use 'tr A-Z a-z' but how do I make sure it is working in the file I want and only on the 11th column.

Answer (score 1):

It depends what you mean by *".csv file"*

In the general case (where quoted CSV fields may contain embedded separator characters, like `"foo,bar",baz`) you will need to use a tool that can correctly parse that such as one of the Perl / Python / Ruby modules - or Miller.

Ex. given:

```
$ cat file.csv
ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE,TEN,ELEVEN,TWELVE
```

then

```
$ mlr --csv --implicit-csv-header --headerless-csv-output put '$11 = tolower($11)' file.csv
ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE,TEN,eleven,TWELVE
```

For *simple* comma delimited fields, you could use Awk or even Sed:

```
$ awk -F, 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} {$11 = tolower($11)} {print}' file.csv
ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE,TEN,eleven,TWELVE

$ sed -E 's/([^,]+)/\L\1/11' file.csv
ONE,TWO,THREE,FOUR,FIVE,SIX,SEVEN,EIGHT,NINE,TEN,eleven,TWELVE
```